# Tensorflow feature column for variable list of values

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

From the TensorFlow docs it's clear how to use `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list` to create a feature column which takes as input some string and outputs a one-hot vector. For example

```
vocabulary_feature_column =
    tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key="vocab_feature",
        vocabulary_list=["kitchenware", "electronics", "sports"])
```

Let's say `"kitchenware"` maps to `[1,0,0]` and `"electronics"` maps to `[0,1,0]`. My question is related to having a **list of strings** as a feature. For example, if the feature value was `["kitchenware","electronics"]` then the desired output would be `[1,1,0]`. The input list length is not fixed but the output dimension is.

The use case is a straight bag-of-words type model (obviously with a much larger vocabulary list!).

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use tf.feature_column.indicator_column
see https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column

Comment: Could you give an example of what the structure of the training data should look like in this case. The doc you post to show what the input data inso converted into but not what you feed it.

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example how to feed data to the indicator column:

```
features = {'letter': [['A','A'], ['C','D'], ['E','F'], ['G','A'], ['X','R']]}

letter_feature = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
                "letter", ["A", "B", "C"], dtype=tf.string)

indicator = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(letter_feature)
tensor = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, [indicator])

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
    print(session.run([tensor]))
```

Which outputs:

```
[array([[2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: in above example the features is passed as dict. How do I get the same results when I have a column in csv file which is space separated and I need to multi-hot encode using the example above ?

Comment: Can we use Embedding column here? In case we have large number of values in the column (a very common case), we may end up with a sparse column if we use indicator column. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns .. Check out this tutorial from Tensorflow, they use Embedding columns here. :)