# tensorflow feed list feature (multi-hot) to tf.estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Some of the feature columns' data type is `list`. And their length can be different. I want to encode this column as a multi-hot categorical feature and feed it to `tf.estimator`. I tried the following but the error `Unable to get element as bytes` showed. I think this is a common practice in deep learning especially recommendation systems e.g. Deep & Wide model. I found a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697799/tensorflow-feature-column-for-variable-list-of-values) but it doesn't show how to feed to the estimator.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

OUTDIR = "./data"

data = {"x": [["a", "c"], ["a", "b"], ["b", "c"]], "y": ["x", "y", "z"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Y = df["y"]
X = df.drop("y", axis=1)

indicator_features = [
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
        categorical_column=tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
            key="x", vocabulary_list=["a", "b", "c"]
        )
    )
]

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
    feature_columns=indicator_features, model_dir=OUTDIR
)

training_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x=X, y=Y, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None
)

model.train(input_fn=training_input_fn)
```

The following error:

> INFO:tensorflow:Using default config. INFO:tensorflow:Using config:
>   {'_model_dir': 'testalg', '_tf_random_seed': None,
>   '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None,
>   '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': None,
>   '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000,
>   '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn':
>   None, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec':
>   , '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0,
>   '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '',
>   '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
>   INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn. INFO:tensorflow:Done calling
>   model_fn. INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized. INFO:tensorflow:Running
>   local_init_op. INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , Unable to
>   get element as bytes. INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into
>   testalg/model.ckpt.
>   ------------------------------------------------------- InternalError         Traceback (most recent call last)
>   /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1321     try:
>   -> 1322       return fn(*args)    1323     except errors.OpError as e:
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata) 
>   1306       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
>   -> 1307           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)    1308
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
>   target_list, run_metadata)    1408           self._session, options,
>   feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
>   -> 1409           run_metadata)    1410     else:
>
> InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> InternalError         Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>        44 
>        45 
>   ---> 46 model.train(input_fn=training_input_fn)
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in train(self, input_fn, hooks, steps, max_steps, saving_listeners)
>       364 
>       365       saving_listeners = _check_listeners_type(saving_listeners)
>   --> 366       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
>       367       logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
>       368       return self
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)    1117
>   return self._train_model_distributed(input_fn, hooks,
>   saving_listeners)    1118     else:
>   -> 1119       return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)    1120     1121   def _train_model_default(self,
>   input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners):
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in _train_model_default(self, input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
>   1133       return self._train_with_estimator_spec(estimator_spec,
>   worker_hooks,    1134
>   hooks, global_step_tensor,
>   -> 1135                                              saving_listeners)    1136     1137   def _train_model_distributed(self, input_fn, hooks,
>   saving_listeners):
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py
>   in _train_with_estimator_spec(self, estimator_spec, worker_hooks,
>   hooks, global_step_tensor, saving_listeners)    1334       loss = None
>   1335       while not mon_sess.should_stop():
>   -> 1336         _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])    1337     return loss    1338
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py
>   in **exit**(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback)
>       687     if exception_type in [errors.OutOfRangeError, StopIteration]:
>       688       exception_type = None
>   --> 689     self._close_internal(exception_type)
>       690     # **exit** should return True to suppress an exception.
>       691     return exception_type is None
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py
>   in _close_internal(self, exception_type)
>       724         if self._sess is None:
>       725           raise RuntimeError('Session is already closed.')
>   --> 726         self._sess.close()
>       727       finally:
>       728         self._sess = None
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py
>   in close(self)
>       972     if self._sess:
>       973       try:
>   --> 974         self._sess.close()
>       975       except _PREEMPTION_ERRORS:
>       976         pass
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py
>   in close(self)    1116       self._coord.join(    1117
>   stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_period_secs,
>   -> 1118           ignore_live_threads=True)    1119     finally:    1120       try:
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py
>   in join(self, threads, stop_grace_period_secs, ignore_live_threads)
>       387       self._registered_threads = set()
>       388       if self._exc_info_to_raise:
>   --> 389         six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
>       390       elif stragglers:
>       391         if ignore_live_threads:
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in
>   reraise(tp, value, tb)
>       683             value = tp()
>       684         if value.**traceback** is not tb:
>   --> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>       686         raise value
>       687
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_queue_runner.py
>   in _run(self, sess, enqueue_op, feed_fn, coord)
>        92         try:
>        93           feed_dict = None if feed_fn is None else feed_fn()
>   ---> 94           sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
>        95         except (errors.OutOfRangeError, errors.CancelledError):
>        96           # This exception indicates that a queue was closed.
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>       898     try:
>       899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>   --> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
>       901       if run_metadata:
>       902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>   1133     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and
>   feed_dict_tensor):    1134       results = self._do_run(handle,
>   final_targets, final_fetches,
>   -> 1135                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)    1136     else:    1137       results = []
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
>   run_metadata)    1314     if handle is None:    1315       return
>   self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
>   -> 1316                            run_metadata)    1317     else:    1318       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)
>
> /home/yinan.li1/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py
>   in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1333         except KeyError:    1334 
>   pass
>   -> 1335       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)    1336     1337   def _extend_graph(self):
>
> InternalError: Unable to get element as bytes.

Comment: Maybe this one will give you some inspiration
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028898/how-i-tensorflow-handle-categorical-features-with-multiple-inputs-within-on-colu

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the problems in your case is that the type of column in pandas is actually object not string. If you converted that to separate string columns you would get rid of this error. Keep in mind that `The basic TensorFlow tf.string dtype allows you to build tensors of byte strings.` and as you are storing object in this column not a string you get an error.

The code below will get overcome the error you get above, but it will not solve your problem completely. The variable lenght of lists would have to be dealt with by padding or the list or something similar as again `indicator_column` might have problems dealing with missing values.

```
X2= pd.DataFrame(X['x'].values.tolist(), columns=['x1','x2'])

feat1 = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
            key="x1", vocabulary_list=["a", "b", "c"]
        )
feat2 = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
            key="x2", vocabulary_list=["a", "b", "c"]
        )
indicator_features = [
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
        categorical_column=feat1
    ),tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
        categorical_column=feat2
    )
]

training_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x=X2, y=Y, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None
)
```